# 2 year old's appointment not done but parents done, can we take him along

Tags: visas, uk, applications, minors

we have 2 appointments for me and my husband at VFS for a visitor visa. unfortunately my 2 year old's appointment did not get get through though his application is completed and payment made. Now since his email address is locked, should we go ahead and take him along with us for the appointment?

Comment: Simply using common sense I would wonder what else a couple would do with their two year-old child when the other two have an interview. However, common sense is not always the best advice in visa cases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while the common-sense answer would be ‘yes’, for a definitive answer the OP should contact the VFS Support team.